# Export R text2vec Vectors for use in Gensim in Python

Tags: python, r, gensim, text2vec

I have created GloVE vectors in R previously using `text2vec` library.

Is there any easy way to export these for use in Python where I have scripts to compare/contract with Gensim created word vectors?  I know there is a specific word2vec c_format, but Im not sure if R has the capability of producing this.

Comment: Does `text2vec` save trained vectors to any format? (The `GLoVe` project's format is nearly the same as the format supported by `load_word2vec_format()`, just without one header line, and gensim has a utility function in `gensim.scripts.glove2word2vec.glove2word2vec` to add the needed line.)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the word2vec R package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/word2vec/index.html. It has facilities to write the wordvectors in binary and text format. See http://bnosac.be/index.php/blog/100-word2vec-in-r